# Replacing missing values by group and identifying mutual exclusiveness

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am working with the grouped data in R.

In the following data example, I would like to fill the missing values in "sex" variable, and keep as is if there was no corresponding data (i.e. for id=6).

In the "diagnosis" variable, some had only one diagnosis and some had multiple diagnosis. So, I also would like to group the variable "diagnosis" into "wanted" to identify mutual exclusiveness.

The example data is;

```
d.f <- tribble (
~id, ~sex, ~diagnosis,
1, "M", "A",
1, NA, "B",
1, NA, "C",
2, NA, "A",
2, "F", NA,
2, NA, "A",
3, NA, NA,
3, "M", "A",
3, "M", "B",
4, "F", "C",
5, "F", "B",
6, NA, "A",
7, "M", NA
)
```

The desired data is ;

```
wanted <- tribble (
~id, ~sex, ~diagnosis,~wanted,
1, "M", "A", "ABC group",
1, "M", "B", "ABC group",
1, "M", "C", "ABC group",
2, "F", "A", "Only A",
2, "F", NA, "Only A",
2, "F", "A", "Only A",
3, "M", NA, "AB group",
3, "M", "A", "AB group",
3, "M", "B", "AB group",
4, "F", "C", "Only C",
5, "F", "B", "Only B",
6, NA, "A", "Only A",
7, "M", NA, "Missing"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  drop_na(diagnosis) %>% 
  summarise(wanted = str_c(c(unique(diagnosis)), collapse = "")) %>% 
  full_join(df1, . , by = "id") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(sex, .direction = "updown")
```

```
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [7]
#>       id sex   diagnosis wanted
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr> 
#>  1     1 M     A         ABC   
#>  2     1 M     B         ABC   
#>  3     1 M     C         ABC   
#>  4     2 F     A         A     
#>  5     2 F     <NA>      A     
#>  6     2 F     A         A     
#>  7     3 M     <NA>      AB    
#>  8     3 M     A         AB    
#>  9     3 M     B         AB    
#> 10     4 F     C         C     
#> 11     5 F     B         B     
#> 12     6 <NA>  A         A     
#> 13     7 M     <NA>      <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

- mutate `sex` column by using `first(na.omit(sex))` `first` is just an aggregating function which is safe to use here
- another column say `wanted` can be mutated in two steps.

  - paste all strings together in the group using `paste(unique(na.omit(diagnosis)), collapse = '')`
  - thereafter use case_when to mutate strings as per your choice

```r
library(tidyverse)

d.f %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(sex = first(na.omit(sex)),
         wanted = { x <- paste(unique(na.omit(diagnosis)), collapse = ''); 
         case_when(nchar(x) == 1 ~  paste0('Only ', x),
                   nchar(x) == 0 ~ 'Missing',
                   TRUE ~ paste(x, ' Group'))})
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [7]
#>       id sex   diagnosis wanted    
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     
#>  1     1 M     A         ABC  Group
#>  2     1 M     B         ABC  Group
#>  3     1 M     C         ABC  Group
#>  4     2 F     A         Only A    
#>  5     2 F     <NA>      Only A    
#>  6     2 F     A         Only A    
#>  7     3 M     <NA>      AB  Group 
#>  8     3 M     A         AB  Group 
#>  9     3 M     B         AB  Group 
#> 10     4 F     C         Only C    
#> 11     5 F     B         Only B    
#> 12     6 <NA>  A         Only A    
#> 13     7 M     <NA>      Missing
```

Comment: The following message came                                                                                             >Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `sex`.
i `sex = first(na.omit(sex))`.
i `sex` must be size 1, not 0.
i The error occurred in group 6: id = 6.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be used:

```
library(dplyr)

d.f %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(sex = coalesce(sex, sex[!is.na(sex)][1]), 
         wanted = across(diagnosis, ~ {x <- unique(diagnosis[!is.na(diagnosis)])
         if_else(length(x) > 1, paste(paste(x, collapse = ""), "Group"), 
                 if_else(length(x) == 1, paste("Only", x[1]), "Missing")
         )}))

# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   id [7]
      id sex   diagnosis wanted$diagnosis
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <chr>           
 1     1 M     A         ABC Group       
 2     1 M     B         ABC Group       
 3     1 M     C         ABC Group       
 4     2 F     A         Only A          
 5     2 F     NA        Only A          
 6     2 F     A         Only A          
 7     3 M     NA        AB Group        
 8     3 M     A         AB Group        
 9     3 M     B         AB Group        
10     4 F     C         Only C          
11     5 F     B         Only B          
12     6 NA    A         Only A          
13     7 M     NA        Missing
```